# If clause not working, every time falls to else part

Tags: javascript, jquery

My scripts return data does not work as should. Where does it go wrong? Tried firebug but i am not so advanced that it would have helped me. Also it does return data i expect it to return but if -clause is not working as i would like it to work.

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function (a) {
        var thisForm = $(this);
        a.preventDefault();
        $(this).fadeOut(function () {
            $("#loading2").fadeIn(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: thisForm.attr("action"),
                    data: thisForm.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        result = data;
                        $("#loading2").fadeOut(function () {
                            $("#success2").text(data).fadeIn();

                            if (result == "okie") {
                                x = "Good day";
                                document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = Tulos + x;
                            } else {
                                x = "Good evening";
                                document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = Tulos + x;
                            }

                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    })
});
```

This all works until `if` part. Php file where the form is first submitted returns "okie" or "t". When the `if(result == "okie")` part runs it takes me to the `else` part every single time.

```
  if (result == "okie") {
      x = "Good day";
      document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = result + x;
  } else {
      x = "Good evening";
      document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = result + x;
  }
```

If result is okie, it changes element data as "okieGood evening" and when it is "t" it changes element as "tGood evening". Should it be "okieGood day" when php returns okie? I put the result to html also so i can be 100% sure what does the php return to me.

I want to add follow up question, what causes my code to write result data on the screen before the if clause?

Comment: try to `.trim()` your result.

Comment: Install firebug and you can see the actual return from the ajax call.

Comment: Or at least console.log(result);

Comment: Do a `trim` as @jayharris suggests. If that doesn't fix it, you can put in an `alert('<' + result + '>')` or something like that to see what you're actually getting, or do a log.

Comment: What does that `Tulos` part mean?

Comment: Here is a link showing how to inspect AJAX request responses using Firebug http://getfirebug.com/network

Comment: This is a potentially dangerous use of `result` since it is a used as a global variable, the `fadeOut` method run asynchronously and if some other method changes the value of `result` in similar way it will affect the value of `result` in the complete callback of `fadeOut`. So make result as a closure variable using `var result = data;`

Comment: `(result.replace(/^\W*|\W*$/g,"") == "okie")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it using $.trim() like this:

`if($.trim(result) == 'okie') {`

Answer (score 0):

we can't really help you if we cant see the response.

but this is what you do, open your firebug or "inspect element" in chorme, and view the network, than when you create an ajax call you should check the response you get from the server.

make sure that the response has no spaces or something like that,
to check you response threw client side you could: console.log(result);
to see the result of that variable.

I would warmly recommend you to start working with json responses instead of simple html.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because of the leading spaces in the `result` variable. Remember `"okie" is not equal to " okie"`. Notice the spaces. You should remove all the spaces from the beginning using trim() function.

Inspect using firebug what is returned after you invoke a request using `AJAX.`

Answer (score 0):

if this isn't the solution, then you need to check your server script.

```
var result = data.trim();
```

Comment: I used 
    var Tulos = $.trim(data);
and it did the trick! Thanks to everyone! :)

Comment: I mean result = $.trim(data); - More better to use not my native language variable names..